# Having the same charset and collation between Redshift and MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, collation, redshift, character-set

I looking to migrate data between Redshift table and MySQL that has a string column. There are a few differences between each engine:

1. Redshift is case sensitive, and by default MySQL isn't.
2. MySQL, depending on the version, can be `latin1` `utf8` or `utf8mb4`.

It came down, as I see it, that in order for it to be the same I need to set the string column in mysql as `CHARSET utf8mb4` and `COLLATION` as either `utf8mb4_general_bin` or `utf8mb4_unicode_bin`. This is by my hunch as testing it might be problematic.

I wonder, is there a way to know for certain which charset and collation redshift uses?

If you're wondering on the table DDL:

```
-- redshift
CREATE TABLE tbl(
  id bigint,
  title varchar(255),
  primary key(id)
)

-- mysql
CREATE TABLE tbl(
  id bigint,
  title varchar(255) CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATION utfmb4_unicode_bin,
  primary key(id),
  unique key (title)
)
```

Comment: *Redshift is case sensitive, MySQL isn't.* ?? In MySQL the case sensitivity depends on its settings (objects) or applied collation (values).

Comment: *and COLLATION as either utf8mb4_general_bin or utf8mb4_unicode_bin* No, this collation provides not case sensitivity but binary code equiality.

Comment: @Akina binary equality collations importantly result in case sensitivity as well, which is [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html): "*If you want a column always to be treated in case-sensitive fashion, declare it with a case-sensitive **or binary collation**.*".

Comment: @J.D. Binary collation should be used for absolute comparings which are applied to the text data too rare. Rather than case sensitive collation which may, for example, need in common and accented letter to be equal. Binary collation cannot. Anycase the collation must match the task - OP have not described it in details.

Comment: I don't get your last comment @Akina . In any case, I want to be able to store the string both in redshift and mysql without errors (charset/collation among others) and that `SELECT Distinct` will provide the same exact result/record count.